# What is the meaning of this symbol ? $a)$ $C_b^0(\mathbb{R})$ $b)$ $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: general-topology

What  is  the meaning  of this  symbol ?

$a)$ $C_b^0(\mathbb{R})$

$b)$ $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

actually im asking  this  question because  i found  the  answer  [Which of the following subsets are dense in the given spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273502/which-of-the-following-subsets-are-dense-in-the-given-spaces)

i didn't  understand the option $b)$

Notes:  i have  seen the user those who have been answer   have not active  since  for  20 days ,,   so  i decide  to upload a new post

thanks  u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the question,

1. space of bounded [the foot $b$] continuous functions [$\mathcal C^0$] defined on $\Bbb R$.
2. space of infinitely differentiable functions [$\mathcal C^\infty$] with compact support [the foot $c$] defined on $\mathbb R$.

support: the closure of the set $\{x \in \mathbb R\colon f(x) \neq 0\}$.

Comment: thanks @xbh im notgetting    how  closure$  \{f(x) \neq 0 \}$??   is  there any theorem

Comment: That's the definition of "support", see the [closed support](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) part. The notation could be $\mathrm {supp}(f)$.

Comment: thanks u.. @xbh

Comment: Glad to help here.